# File (image) only exists when searching for it or in "Photos" app

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystem-corruption, file-search

Here's a weird thing that I've never seen before in any Windows version. I'm using Windows 10.

I'm using the stock "Photos" app to view some pictures that I've been editing, and when scrolling through them, an old version of it appears along with the new one.

The thing is, it doesn't appear to be on the disk. I tried removing it through the Photos app, it isn't there when browsing with File Explorer.

When I search for it, the problematic file appears, but cannot be deleted:

[image: Screenshot: search finds the file, but cannot delete.]

Here is a full screenshot showing both the actual folder and the "ghost" image in Photos:

[image: Screenshot: ghost file in Photos app, not in explorer.]

What's happening and how can I fix this?

I've already ran CCleaner with full options, and rebooted PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to preview the ghost file in full screen (rather than thumbnail image) using Photos, it's probably there. To check if the file is in that specified location, try this:

Press WinKey + R and type in:

```
cmd /k cd/d "z:\pictures\photos\2015\Duitsland juli"
```

Type:

```
Dir dsc_0001*.* /a
```

Is the file listed?